# Camera shows black first time launching unity app on android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, permissions, camera, android-manifest

I have a unity app which uses the camera to scan QR Codes, however when I run the app for the first time on android the camera just shows black. If I restart the app the camera works fine, but it's really annoying telling every customer to restart the app for it to work, and this problem doesn't exist on iOS, only android.

Before I made any changes to the AndroidManifest.xml it was requesting permission from the user for camera access and when giving it permission it'd still only show black. I've tried adding this to the Android Manifest, but so far no luck

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Just in case I got this wrong, the AndroidManifest.xml file is located at ProjectRoot/Assets/Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml

I'm certain this is the camera not working, and not something overlaying on the camera display, because in the android emulator it doesn't give me camera controls

Comment: Did you check the logcat for possible errors? Unity has an in-editor logcat which you can install with the new package manager if you don't know how to open it.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe asking for permissions at runtime is an async function so the camera fails to open the first time the app runs. I have the same thing happening, I tried IEnumerator Update() and basically waiting until user decides whether the camera permission will be given or not, didn't help. I have to kill the app after giving camera permission and start the App again. I am sure there is an easy solution but so far all my scripting tries failed. Same goes to STORAGE PERMISSION, first time try to save a photo after clean install of the App it fails, need to give permission and save again. Once all the permissions are given all is good. Using android API 29 device with build supporting API 33.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).